# Slideshow jumps on top

Tags: jquery, slideshow

my slideshow is working very fine but every "next" or "prev" the entire page is jumping on top. This is annoying, especially on lower resolutions and mobile devices.
Here is the slideshow: http://www.edelsteine-wimmer.at
Thank you for your help! :)

Code:

```
var Eva = Eva || {};

function set_testimonial_page(page) {

  Eva.testimonial_page = page;
  $('.testimonial').hide();
  $('.testimonial').removeClass('active');
  $('#testimonial' + page).fadeIn(500);
  $('#testimonial' + page).addClass('active');
  $('#testimonial-count').html(page + ' von ' + $('.testimonial').length);

}

$(document).ready(function() {

  // testimonials

  var testimonials = $('.testimonial').length;
  set_testimonial_page(1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * testimonials));
  $('#testimonial-prev').click(function(event) {

      //event.preventDefault();

      Eva.testimonial_page--;
      if (Eva.testimonial_page < 1) Eva.testimonial_page = testimonials;
      set_testimonial_page(Eva.testimonial_page);

  });

  $('blockquote, #testimonial-next , #testimonial- count').click(function(event) {

      //event.preventDefault();
      Eva.testimonial_page++;
      if (Eva.testimonial_page > testimonials) Eva.testimonial_page = 1;
      set_testimonial_page(Eva.testimonial_page);

  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the HTML. The link that you provided has two arrows which have `href` to `#`. This makes the page go to the first element. As you want to display only testimonials, instead of :

```
<li class="testimonial-arrow first">
  <a id="testimonial-prev" href="#">«</a>
</li>
```

modify the `href` to :

```
<li class="testimonial-arrow first">
  <a id="testimonial-prev" href="#thankyous">«</a>
</li>
```

Do this for both the arrows, and the page stays on the testimonials when the arrows are clicked.

Comment: @EvaKathrinWimmer Please choose it as the correct answer to end this Q & A.